# Java script check dynamically check box is click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating radio button dynamically.

```
@model IList<HireItemModel.HireItemSeparatetModel>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var val = item.pId;     

     <tr>
     <td> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="@val" />

    </td>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.pname) 
   </td>
       <td> - $</td>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
   </td>

   </tr>
}
```

So I want to check the one of the check box is click in java script.
So How can I do it?

I'm using C# asp.net MVC.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to detect an onclick event, or whether you want to check whether a checkbox is checked. You should research both: there's _plenty_ of information on this if you search on Google. At the moment I'm putting in a -1 for lack of research, and lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each checkbox has a checked property:

```
var i, tmpVal,
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("chk_group"); // array of checkboxes

for(i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){

    //based on your code, it looks like you may want to check the value prop
    tmpVal = checkboxes[i].getAttribute("value");

    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        // ...do something
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hobbs is right though... You could have searched google and found this answer pretty quickly.  I didn't think you were asking about click events, but you should look up window.addEventListener() if that's what you're looking for